# Can't run cron in Laravel 5.4 (PHP7) with Docker

Tags: docker, laravel-5, cron

Here is a problem - we updated Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 5.4 using Docker and this container https://github.com/shin1x1/docker-laravel-on-php7-apache

PHP version is increased from 5.X to 7.
We have this cronjob

```
* * * * * php /var/www/laravel/artisan schedule:run >>/dev/null 2>&1
```

That works fine on previous build, 
also runnig this command

```
php /var/www/laravel/artisan schedule:run >>/dev/null 2>&1
```

directly from SSH is fine too.

But it doesn't run via cron.

We modified cron command to make an output like this

```
  * * * * * php /var/www/laravel/artisan schedule:run > /etc/log/faillog
```

*(I don't remember syntax exactly and can't access that machine now)*

And we get this in log

```
/bin/sh: 1: php: not found
```

Any ideas to get this work?

Comment: Install PHP-CLI.

Comment: As I say it works directly from SSH

Comment: The only reason to get a php not found is to not have it installed. You might have divergence of environments. Maybe the User you're using have php in it's environment and Docker doesn't. Another suggestion is to try and figure out in what path php is installed and use the full path for it. Like `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/laravel/artisan`

Comment: OK, let's try it

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify full path to PHP. In below I used default ubuntu php path. Yours may differ. To find out the full path run command: `which php`

```
  * * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/laravel/artisan schedule:run > /etc/log/faillog
```